# If $2+\log_2a=3+\log_3b=\log_6(a+b)$, find $\frac1a+\frac1b$ and $\log_{ab}\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, roots

I have a kind of system of equations with logarithms.
How do I get to the expression that the problem asks for?
(Taken from the net.)

> If $a>0$ and $b>0$ and it is given that
> $$2+\log_{2}{a} =3+\log_{3}{b}=\log_{6}{(a+b)}$$
>
> find the value of
>
> a) $\quad\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}$
>
> b) $\quad\log_{ab}{\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)}$

**Edit 1**
I have related the first with the third and the second with the third to form a system of equations, but the values that come out are not very comfortable to deal with, I do not know if I am wrong or if the problem is like that.

$$2+\log_{2}{a}=\log_{6}{(a+b)}$$
$$3+\log_{3}{b=}\log_{6}{(a+b)}$$

**Edit 2** :I have reformulated the problem by splitting it in two

Comment: I have spent an hour on this, and saw no approach that was not ugly.  Please double check that you have not made a typo in your query.

Comment: @user2661923 5 Problem well copied, I don't get to anything simple either.could you put some of what you have done maybe some relationship , I am content to get to the expression inside the logarithm as I don't see how to find ab

Comment: I just posted my analysis as a **pseudo-answer**.

Answer (score 3):

Per OP's request

**This is not an answer**.  
However, the work is too long-winded to be placed as a series of comments.

> $a>0$ and $b>0$ 
> $$2+\log_{2}{a} =3+\log_{3}{b}=\log_{6}{(a+b)}$$

> Compute
> $$ \log_{ab}{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)}$$

---

Let $x = \log_2 a, ~y = \log_3 b, ~z = \log_6(a+b) \implies$ 
$2^x = a, 3^y = b,~$ and $~6^z = (a+b).$

Also implied is that $2 + x = 3 + y = z.$

**To Compute**
Find the value $w$ such that $(ab)^w = \frac{a+b}{ab}
= \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right).$

Clearly, $(ab)^{(-1)} = \frac{1}{ab}.$

Therefore, the problem reduces to finding $v$ such that $(ab)^v = (a+b) \implies w = (v-1)$.

From the premises, you know that

- $(ab) = (2^x)(3^y).$
- $(6^z) = (a + b)$.
- $z = x+2$ and $y = x-1$.

Therefore, $(ab) = (2^x)[3^{(x-1)}] = \frac{6^x}{3}.$

Also, $36 \times 6^x = 6^{(x+2)} = 6^z = (a+b).$

Thus, you are looking for $v$ such that 
$\left[\frac{6^x}{3}\right]^v = 36 \times 6^x.$

Therefore, $6^{xv} = (3^v) \times 36 \times 6^x \implies
6^{xv-x} = 36 \times (3^v) \implies$

$$6^{xw} = 36 \times 3 \times 3^w.\tag1$$

Therefore

$[(2^x)]^w \times [3^{(x-1)}]^w = 108 \implies$

$$a^w \times b^w = 108 = \frac{a+b}{ab} \implies
108(ab) = (a+b). \tag2 $$

The above analysis assumes (perhaps wrongly) that I haven't made any algebra mistakes.

**Note** For what it's worth, equation (2) above establishes that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = 108.$

---

After I got to this point, I spent some time trying to solve for the exact value of $w$.  I got nowhere.  This is ugly.  Personally, I outlaw using computer software here, because it (in general) renders analytical attempts somewhat meaningless.

I experimented with setting $r = \log_2(3)$ to see if this yielded some elegant simplification.  It didn't, for me.  I then considered brute force, trying to specifically solve for $a,b,x,y,z,w.$  For me, that approach got ugly, **fast**.

I emphasize: this response **is not an answer**, but is posted as such per OP's request.

Comment: The $108$ is perfectly correct.

Comment: This problem is awful. Cheers :-)

Comment: The truth is that I thank you both for your time, I also came to horrible expressions and I thought I was wrong, I realize that the problem is complex or maybe I have a super artifice that none of you saw.
The second part of the problem I don't see it anywhere if you come up with something please post it, these problems make the bogeyman boil.

Answer (score 3):

*A probably awful solution.*

Rewrite the sustem as
$$2+\log_{2}{a} =3+\log_{3}{b}=\log_{6}{(a+b)}\color{red}{=k}$$ Switching to natural logarithms
$$2+\frac{\log (a)}{\log (2)}=3+\frac{\log (b)}{\log (3)}=\frac{\log (a+b)}{\log (6)}=k$$
So
$$a=2^{k-2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=3^{k-3}$$ and we face the problem of solving now
$$2^{k-2}+3^{k-3}=6^k \qquad\text{or} \qquad \log(2^{k-2}+3^{k-3})=k\log(6)$$ which cannot show explicit solution. By inspection, the solution is close to $k=-1$ and a first iteration of Newton method will give
$$k\sim -1-\frac{89 \log \left(\frac{108}{89}\right)}{81 \log (3)+6\log (2)}$$ and then *estimates* of $a$ and $b$. Using them
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1b \approx 108.024$$
$$\log_{ab}{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)}\approx -0.688551$$ which looks like $-\log(2)$.

Using Newton method for an almost exact solution, shows the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & k_n \\
 0 & -1.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & -1.1821700749166010948 \\
 2 & -1.1819646254300294942 \\
 3 & -1.1819646251791712419
\end{array}
\right)$$ Using this number
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1b = 108.0000000000000000000000\cdots$$ but this does not improve the second result.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is best approached backwards.

$$\begin{align}\log_{ab}\bigg(\frac1a+\frac 1b\bigg)=\log_{ab}\bigg(\frac{a+b}{ab}\bigg)=\log_{ab}(a+b)-1\\=\frac{\log_6(a+b)}{\log_6(ab)}-1=\frac{\log_6(a+b)}{\log_6(a)+\log_6(b)}-1=\frac{\log_6(a+b)}{\frac{\log_2(a)}{1+\log_2(3)}+\frac{\log_3(b)}{1+\log_3(2)}}-1\\=\frac{\log_3(6)\log_6(a+b)}{\log_3(2)\log_2(a)+\log_3(b)}-1=\frac{\log_3(108)}{\log_3(2)\log_2(a)+(\log_2(a)-1)}\\=\frac{\log_3(108)}{\log_3(ab)}=\log_{ab}(108)\end{align}$$
which implies that $\frac 1a+\frac 1b=108$, as others found.

I can't yet find the last step needed to finish it (without approximating $a$ and $b$) but I think I'm close.

Comment: I certainly wish you luck in trying to compute the exact value of the logarithm.  You are welcome to steal any ideas that you wish from my pseudo-answer, such as assigning variables to some of the logarithms to facilitate algebraic manipulations.  Actually, it is somewhat counter-intuitive that some elegant simplification does not exist, because otherwise, one questions why the problem would be internet-posted.  Personally, I couldn't crack it.

Comment: Yes, having no way (to my knowledge at least) to interpret $\log(p)\log(q)$ is causing me no end of suffering.

Comment: Suppose (for example) $f = \log_2(p), g = \log_2(q).$ Then $2^{(fg)} = \left(2^f\right)^g = p^g.$  So you are stuck trying to evaluate $p^g$ knowing only that $2^g = q$.  To me this **seems** like chasing your tail.  However, as I say, whoever posted this nightmare is either a brilliant sadist, had some elegance in mine, **or both**.

Comment: Further, attempting to use that $108 = \frac{a+b}{ab}$ is no walk in the park.

Comment: Actually, where I'm up to combined with the $108$ you found shows that $$\log_{ab}(108)=\frac{\log_3(108)}{\text{mess}}\implies\text{mess}=\log_3(ab)$$ Maybe that could be useful. Edit: nope

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't really a middle ground here.  Either you can obtain a closed form expression (or perhaps limit of a convergent series) for the logarithm, or you can't.  If you do find the expression, please flag me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer attempts to find part b).

---

Let us prove that $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$. From the LHS:

$$\exp(\ln (a^{\log_b c}) ) = \exp(\log_b (c \ln a)) = \exp(\ln c /\ln b \cdot\ln a) = \exp(\ln a / \ln b \cdot \ln c) = \exp(\log_b( a \ln c))$$
$$ = \exp(\ln (c^{\log_b a})) = c^{\log_b a} = \text{RHS}$$

Raising $6$ to the power of both sides:

$$36 \cdot 6^{\log_2 a} = 216 \cdot 6^{\log_3 b} = a+b$$
$$\Rightarrow 36 \cdot a^{\log_2 6} = 216 \cdot b^{\log_3 6} = a+b \tag{using the above property}$$
$$\Rightarrow 36a \cdot a^{\log_2 3} = 216b \cdot b^{\log_3 2} = a+b$$

and taking the logarithm base-$ab$ of both sides:

$$\frac{\log_a (36a \cdot a^{\log_2 3})}{\log_a ab} = \frac{\log_b(216b \cdot b^{\log_3 2})}{\log_b ab} = \log_{ab} (a+b)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1 + \log_a 36 + \log_2 3}{1 + \log_a b} = \frac{1 + \log_b 216 + \log_2 3}{1 + \log_b a} = \log_{ab} (a+b)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\log_a 36/b + \log_2 3}{1 + \log_a b} = \frac{\log_b 216/a + \log_2 3}{1 + \log_b a} = \log_{ab}(a+b) - \log_{ab}(ab) = \log_{ab}(1/a+1/b)$$

where in the last step, we have subtracted $1$ from each term.

Comment: The way forward is probably to use the fact that $36 = \frac{1/a+1/b}{3}, 216 = 2(1/a+1/b)$.

Comment: I think that a comment that I gave to a different *answerer* bears repeating: Unfortunately, there isn't really a middle ground here. Either you can obtain a closed form expression (or perhaps limit of a convergent series) for the logarithm, or you can't. If you do find the expression, please flag me.

Comment: for the dedicated effort of those who have participated, which is beyond my capabilities, I must say that the problem at first I looked at it less, I tried to solve it coming to similar expressions thinking of an elegant answer, but the truth is macabre.
Thank you for your time